# How to add reveal in animation at the start of a screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, widget

I have an app and I want a 'reveal in animation' where when the screen is initialized, the elements I want look like they are 'moving inside' the screen. I think using `AnimatedPositioned` would be the correct option but I am not able to do with the code I have right now. My elements are in the following widget hierarchy so please answer accordingly.

```
Scaffold
 - Row 
  - Padding
   - Column
    - Container (widget I want to reveal in)
    - Container (widget I want to reveal in)
  - Padding
   - Column
    - Container (widget I want to reveal in)
    - Container (widget I want to reveal in)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use PositionedTransition, where you can set begin and end. You can try to [follow this article](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PositionedTransition-class.html). I works like this:

```
PositionedTransition(
              rect: RelativeRectTween(
                begin: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                end: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(100.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              ).animate(_animationController),
              child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.red,),
            ),
```

Pls let me know if it helped. Cheers

Comment: what do the smallLogo and bigLogo mean?

Comment: it was code from example. I edited the the answer with something more simple. You will have to tweak the RelativeRectTween and animation to achieve the animation you want